# Windows: List shares and permissions using Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

I have a Windows2012R2 server with many shares.

Each share has assigned some groups for granting permissions, for example:

> Share.................................|
> Groups...................................
>
> \\Server\Accounting...   | Acc_RW, Acc_R, Admins
>
> \\Server\Controling...   | Cont_RW, Cont_R, Admins
>
> etc.

Using "Get-SmbShareAccess -Name Accounting" I can get a list of all permissions for the Accounting share but how can I get a list of all all shares and their assigned permissions without do it manually for each share?

Comment: Run a `foreach` loop and iterate to get the permission list. Store them in an array according to your need.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to export a kind of *report*, you should use something like code below, but please note that for technical purposes such as migration, copying, etc, it is better to use `Get-SmbShare` with props like `SecurityDescriptor`, `FolderEnumerationMode`, etc.. (see `Get-SmbShare | Select *`)

---

Sample report:

```
Get-SmbShare | 
    ForEach-Object {Get-SmbShareAccess -InputObject $_} |
    Select-Object @(
        @{Name = 'ReportDate'; Expression = {[DateTime]::Today.ToString('yyyy.MM.dd')}}
        @{Name = 'ShareName'; Expression = {$_.Name}}
        'AccountName'
        'AccessControlType'
        'AccessRight'
    ) |
    Format-Table -AutoSize 

<# RESULT:
ReportDate ShareName AccountName              AccessControlType AccessRight
---------- --------- -----------              ----------------- -----------
2023.09.25 ADMIN$    BUILTIN\Administrators               Allow        Full
2023.09.25 ADMIN$    BUILTIN\Backup Operators             Allow        Full
2023.09.25 ADMIN$    NT AUTHORITY\INTERACTIVE             Allow        Full
2023.09.25 C$        BUILTIN\Administrators               Allow        Full
2023.09.25 C$        BUILTIN\Backup Operators             Allow        Full
2023.09.25 C$        NT AUTHORITY\INTERACTIVE             Allow        Full
2023.09.25 D$        BUILTIN\Administrators               Allow        Full
2023.09.25 D$        BUILTIN\Backup Operators             Allow        Full
#>
```

Or something a little bit more complex:

```
Get-SmbShare | 
ForEach-Object {
    return [PSCustomObject]@{
        Share = $_
        ShareAccess = @(Get-SmbShareAccess -InputObject $_)
        }
    } |
    ForEach-Object {  
        $Share = $_.Share
        $_.ShareAccess | 
            Select-Object @(
                @{Name = 'ShareName'; Expression = {$Share.Name}}
                @{Name = 'SharePath'; Expression = {$Share.Path}}
                'AccessControlType'
                'AccessRight'
                'AccountName'
            )
    } |
    Format-Table -AutoSize 

<# RESULT:
ShareName SharePath    AccessControlType AccessRight AccountName             
--------- ---------    ----------------- ----------- -----------             
ADMIN$    C:\WINDOWS               Allow        Full BUILTIN\Administrators  
ADMIN$    C:\WINDOWS               Allow        Full BUILTIN\Backup Operators
ADMIN$    C:\WINDOWS               Allow        Full NT AUTHORITY\INTERACTIVE
C$        C:\                      Allow        Full BUILTIN\Administrators  
C$        C:\                      Allow        Full BUILTIN\Backup Operators
C$        C:\                      Allow        Full NT AUTHORITY\INTERACTIVE
D$        D:\                      Allow        Full BUILTIN\Administrators  
#>
```